# Set YouTube homepage to avoid content by keyword

Tags: youtube

Is there a way to setup my YouTube account so that videos corresponding to certain keywords will never be shown in my homepage?

ex.  set up "Glasses" as keyword, never receiving content related to glasses in my homepage.